# Replac'g 2 incandes. candelabra bulbs for new dimmable 5W LEDs on porch lt.They won't turn on. Work in lamp, however. Wall switch is elect. timer

Tags: light-fixture

FYI from OP: I don't NEED dimmer capability and won't use (they just happen to offer them this way). New LEDs are generic with very good reviews. Output of LEDs is supposed to be 40W equivalency. Incandescent work in old porch light.

Comment: Model number of timer?

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem with lights in a cabinet. The LED replacement bulbs are longer from the tip to the start of the threaded shell and failed to make contact in the sockets. The sockets did not have a threaded metal shell as is usually found in the U.S., but have a threaded plastic body with a small side contact. (The cabinet was from Denmark in a prior millennium.) A little fiddling about **with the cabinet unplugged** managed to bend the contact to a better place. Similar problems can occur with the tip contact if it has been bent down and the new bulb doesn't reach it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Timer switch is probably not compatible with LEDs.

Comment: Try one incandescent and one LED in the fixture and report results, please. There's  certain variant of porch fixture wiring that twigs a problem with going to LED bulbs because it was running incandescent bulbs in series at half-voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The timer switch is probably a dimmer as well and is not compatible with the LEDs. There are many ways to dime an LED, and not all LEDs (and drivers) will work with all schemes.

Either you have to replace the LEDs or the switch.

Comment: The Model SS7 Intermatic timer is not a dimmer-capable one (no sliding bar) and is hard-wired into the wall switch.  Although it does say it "can be used for flood, compact fluorescent lamps and dimmers".

Comment: Just called Intermatic and they said, as you did, this older model is not compatible with LEDs and will not operate the lights.  Thank you, Rohit.